# Encoding Cyrillic in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, encode, cyrillic

After fetching an xml (with Cyillic symbols) from the site I parse it to dictionary using this code

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
import xml.etree.ElementTree  as ET
def get_class_list():
    url = 'http://samplehtml.com'
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, method = urlfetch.POST)
    root = ET.fromstring(result.content)
    class_list = []
    for child in root[0]:
            class_voc = {}
            class_voc['classid'] = child.find('classid').text
            class_voc['classname'] = child.find('classname').text.encode("utf-8")
            class_list.append(class_voc)
    return class_list
```

I print it to web page (I use google app engine) and get this

```
    [{'classid': '75242', 'classname': '1\xc3\xa0'}, 
{'classid': '75244', 'classname': '1\xc3\xa1'}, 
    {'classid': '75246', 'classname': '1\xc3\xa2'}, 
{'classid': '75243', 'classname': '2\xc3\xa0'}]
```

I tried to encode it to utf-8 but there was no result. How can I decode it to get regular letters?

Okay, the problem is app engine doesn't support this function `unicode('8в','latin1')` which i can use in purpose to compare some values I need to compare, because I either can access unicode representation of chars `'classname': u'1\xe0'` or some arabic like chars `1á` for example. So I need both to compare values and to write them to web page.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.encode("utf-8")` from your code sample?  I suspect that urlfetch returns encoded text so that doing another encoding just messes things up.

Comment: @Kekito Well, yes you're right. After removing `.encode("utf-8")` I got this `{'classid': '75242', 'classname': u'1\xe0'}, {'classid': '75244', 'classname': u'1\xe1'}` so it's I suppose a unicode representation of string. All decoding I've tried end with an error.

Comment: It looks like you want a `decode("cp1251")` somewhere in your code (perhaps on `result.content` before it is passed to `ET.fromstring`?). The escaped codepoints you're seeing in your comment correspond to the letters at the start of the alphabet (`а` and `б`) in that encoding, and the letter you mention in the text `в` is the next one, `\xe2`.

Comment: @Blckknght Well, I did this way     `result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, method = urlfetch.POST)
    content = result.content.decode("cp1251")
    root = ET.fromstring(content)` and got this error `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 97: ordinal not in range(128)` And yes I know those symbols are different from the one I wanted to check. I posted them as an example because they were the first

Comment: It sounds to me like the `content` value is already Unicode then, but incorrectly decoded. I'm not sure how you can tell `urlfetch` to decode it differently though.

Comment: @Blckknght I've just tried to do the same with `urllib2`, but the result was the same, so I don't think the problem is `urlfetch`

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with the website you're fetching? Does it report the wrong character encoding for the data it's sending?

Comment: @Blckknght well, I tried the same request in Google Chrome and got an xml as the result with _windows-1251 (cp1251)_ coding. So I think that `urllib` or `urlfetch` or `requests` libraries decode all data to _utf-8_ by default. The question is how can I decode them back to **cp1251**?